# Как мне соединить таблицы в phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, phpmyadmin, соцсети

Есть таблица `users`, где пишутся логин и пароль, есть отдельная таблица `students`, где вся информация про студента - типа имя, возраст, адрес.

Как мне их соединить, если при регистрации логин и пароль уходят в `users`, а после добавлении информации о студенте инфа уходит в другую?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень странный вопрос. Что значит соединить? Насовсем? Тогда нужно будет создать третью таблицу (или отредактировать одну из них) и написать запрос который копирует данные одной таблицу в другую. Я конечно с SQL не много работал, может есть и получше способ. Но вот с помощью PHP точно можно и делается очень тривиально. Можно и без PHP, чисто SQL. Одним кликом вряд ли вы это сделаете. Хотя может я и ошибаюсь.

Если вам нужно только на время запроса их соединить, используйте Inner Join. Например:

```
SELECT users.login, students.name
FROM users INNER JOIN students WHERE users.id = students.id
```

А сохранить это в таблицу можно так:

```
SELECT users.login, students.name 
INTO newTableName
FROM users INNER JOIN students WHERE users.id = students.id
```